# How to append data to const whar_t*

Tags: c++, stm32

I am building a project based on STM32CubeProgrammer API. The filepath is is done like this and you have to input the filename in the code manually.

```
    /* Download File + verification */
#ifdef _WIN32
    const wchar_t* filePath = L"../test file/filename.hex";
#else
    const wchar_t* filePath = L"../api/test file/filename.hex";
#endif
```

I want the program to show a list of available .hex files, ask for a corresponding number and then append the correct filename to the filePath. The goal is to ask for minimal input from user and keep it as simple as possible.

filePath should remain as const wchar_t*.

I wasn't able to find anything working on Google and I am not even sure how and what to search.

How can this be done?

Comment: Read into a `std::wstring`, use its `c_str()` function to get the `wchar_t*`?

Comment: Yes, that could be an option, but that's not an ideal solution. I edited the question to explain a bit more what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why doesn't changing to `std::wstring` and then using `.c_str()` when you need to `wchar_t*` work? That's the easy solution, and you do say that you want to keep it simple.

Comment: If the goal is to have pointer to constant segment, then it can't be done during run-time. If the goal is to pass pointer to function which argument is `const wchar_t*`, then you don't need pointer to be `const` itself.

Comment: This doesn't look like a compile time feature. Looks like you should use `std::filesystem` `path` and `directory_iterator`.

Comment: You are essentially asking how to construct a C-style string. It seems you want to avoid using the standard library containers, and/or dynamic memory. So just use an array. Copy the path into that array with the C string functions, then append/modify the filename part. Be sure to make your array large enough to cope with anything you might throw at it (including the NUL terminator). As already mentioned, you can pass a non-const pointer to a function that accepts a const parameter. The only restriction is you can't do the reverse (pass a const pointer to a non-const parameter).

Comment: Well, `const` data is constant, by its nature. How do you expect to modify (i.e. append to) such data but, at the same time, keep it as `const`?

Comment: I got it working with solution offered by @Someprogrammerdude. I was overthinking a lot. Thanks to everyone. I posted an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution, thanks to @Someprogrammerdude. User input not yet implemented.

```
        std::wstring projects[] = { L"data.hex", L"blinky.hex" };
        int projectNr = 0;

        std::wstring file = L"../test file/" + projects[projectNr];


#ifdef _WIN32
        const wchar_t* filePath = file.c_str();
#else
        const wchar_t* filePath = L"../api/test file/";
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need, or think that you need, `const wchar_t*` pointer. But instead of trying to "workaround" C++ standard and compilers by appending filename to path you can do it "other way around", i.e. instead of appending you can show only filenames, i.e. something like that:

```
const wchar_t *file_paths[] = {
  "some path/filename1.hex",
  "some path/filename2.hex",
...
};

const wchar_t* select_path() {
  for (const wchar_t *path : file_paths) {
    const wchar_t* filename = get_file_name_from_path(path);
    out_file_name(filename);
  }
  return file_paths[input_number()];
}
```

Comment: 'const wchar_t*' is needed, because it is defined as an input in file download function.

Comment: One more time, if function argument is `const wchar_t*` it doesn't mean that you can't pass just `wchar_t*`, it means that function itself is not allowed to change content to which this pointer points. So, you don't really need to modify `const wchar_t*` pointer.